# Importing data from external drive to Mongodb hosted on Google compute engine

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

I deployed MongoDB on google cloud. I have trouble importing data now. I have a `json` format data on my hard drive, and would like to import it to the database. I tried multiple ways that didn't work:

- directly specifying the location of the file
- saving the file in a Google storage bucket.

These are the commands I ran:

```
mongoimport -d test -c trialcollection - f /mongobucket/trial.json

mongoimport -d test -c trialcollection /mongobucket/trial.json

mongoimport -d test -c trialcollection - f C:/desktop/mongo/trial.json
```

How do I get data to import into Mongo hosted on the Google compute engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the json files on your local computer and you need to mongoimport them into your remove GCE MongoDB instance. The best way to do that is to copy the files that you need over to your GCE instance.

If you haven't already, you should install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) on your local system. After you've installed that, you should be able to use the [gcloud compute copy-files](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) command to copy the files from your local system to your GCE instance. This command essentially works like scp.

From there you can use [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) to connect to your instance and then run the mongoimport command locally on your GCE instance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could copy the data to a remote directory using gcloud compute copy-files and connected to an instance, but unable to change the working directory to the remote directory so that i can use mongoimport.

Comment: The point that I was trying to make is that the you want to have the json files *local* to the mongodb instance AND run mongoimport on that same host. Your situation is not clear at this point. It sounds like you are doing some combination of local/remote files and local/remote mongodb instance. This is likely to not work due to firewall restrictions.

Comment: Saved the .json file to the local directory and it Worked!! Earlier was saving it to a new directory ~/Newdirectory and cd Newdirectory was not working. Now I just saved the .json file to the current working directory specifying ~/ and it worked. Thanks for the help.